# How do I structure a plist to be able to insert, delete, and edit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, uitableview

I'm a complete noob when it comes to iOS programming. I'm trying to write a program where I am able to insert, edit, and delete a tableviewcell based on a plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Factors</key>
    <array>
        <string>Time</string>
        <string>Cost</string>
    </array>
    <key>Rank</key>
    <array>
        <string>10</string>
        <string>9</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Time is related to 10
Cost is related to 9

I want to be able to delete, add, and edit these values within different view controllers.

Am I doing it the proper way? Have I set up my plist in some fashion that will break my code in the future? I want to be able to click on the cell segue into my edit view controller and be able to edit them.

When I delete I want to have it update the plist file. 
I want to be able to display the Factors as the text label and the rank as the detail label.

Am I structuring the plist correctly?

I made two other view controllers for edit and add already. How do I manage the plist through the prepare for segue? I want to be able to pass in the row variables into the fields so that they can later be edited.

Do I have to make another NSObject class just to model this?

I'm super confused right now @.@. What is the proper way or smarter way of doing this?

This is how I have linked up my storyboard so far:
[image]

Is there a tutorial for this?

Here is the repo I'm working with: https://github.com/rlam3/test.git

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably structure the plist more like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Factor</key>
            <string>Time</string>
            <key>Rank</key>
            <string>10</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Factor</key>
            <string>Cost</string>
            <key>Rank</key>
            <string>9</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

I'm asuming the plist is stored on the device, if so you can use:

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

to read the plist into an array.

After mutating it you can then write it back to the plist file by using on the mutaded array:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

You can find more information about these methods @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html